# How to measure time elapsed in Ballerina?

Tags: time, ballerina

I am currently trying to get the execution time for a ballerina function. For that I need to get the timestamp before and after calling the function.
How to get the timestamp in milliseconds using ballerina?

I have tried `time` module and I did not find a direct way to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the common use case to calculate the elapsed time, it is better to use the following API instead of `time:UtcNow()`

```
 decimal now = time: monotonicNow();
```

Do note, `time:monotonicNow` does not guarantee accurate reading of the utc timestamp. It only guarantees continuity i.e it guarantees consistent value increase in subsequent calls with nanoseconds precision.

Answer (score 2):

The `time:utcNow()` function provides all needed details to get the accurate timestamp in milliseconds. This returns a tuple of length 2. The first member of the tuple is int representing an integral number of seconds from the epoch. The second member of the tuple is a decimal giving the fraction of a second. Default precision is in nanoseconds. You can manipulate the `time:Utc` tuple as follows to get the time in milliseconds.

```
time:Utc now = time:utcNow();
int timeInMills = <int>(<decimal>now[0] + now[1]) * 1000;
```

Do note, this can result in negative interval due to the [clock synchronisation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAyW-4LeXZo&t=662s)